Where could we get com.sun.mail from?
We have a javax.mail dependency (here's its latest version). It has a class called javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress which has this import
import com.sun.mail.util.PropUtil;

Here's the only place it's used
    private static final boolean ignoreBogusGroupName = PropUtil.getBooleanSystemProperty("mail.mime.address.ignorebogusgroupname", true);

We have an OpenJDK-based JDK 8 distribution. It doesn't have com.sun.mail at all. It seems OpenJDK 8 itself doesn't have it either (at any rate, I downloaded the archive, manually inspected its contents and didn't find one)
InternetAddress from jakarta.mail doesn't have such an import (jars), it uses jakarta.mail.internet.MimeUtility instead. But migrating to jakarta appears risky (or at least troublesome, I remember the pain of transitioning to jakarta.servlet)
Where could we get com.sun.mail from (or otherwise solve this problem)?

This question is similar to: ClassNotFoundException com.sun.mail.util.SharedByteArrayInputStream. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Don't try to avoid Jakarta mail. It will only give you pain in the long run

@Filburt I don't see how it's related at all (besides the fact that javax.mail is mentioned in both)

It's similar because it is about the javax.mail classes on your class path. It sounds like you have a version conflict. Can you setup a minimal project to reproduce the issue? Eg. A pom.xml and a .java file that either cannot compile or gives you a runtime exception?

JavaMail (now JakartaMail/Angus Mail) never was part of Java itself.

If you go to the source repo for javax.mail (https://github.com/javaee/javamail) and look at its POM file, the dependency the POM uses for com.sun.mail is:
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
   <version>${mail.version}</version>
</dependency>

where mail.version will be the version for the javax.mail dependency.
Try adding that to your project's POM file.

For reference, for JakartaMail 2.x, the coordinates are jakarta.mail:jakarta.mail-api:2.1.3 and org.eclipse.angus:angus-mail:2.0.3 (Angus Mail is the reference implementation of JakartaMail (and is what used to be com.sun.mail:javax.mail).
